# Is it undefined behaviour for a c++ constant initialized in one .o file to depend on one defined in another file?

Tags: c++, constants, c++98, static-initialization, unspecified-behavior

I have a C++ project with `const string` constants in two `.o` files, where the constant in one file is initialized using the value in the other file. This used to work fine, but now that I'm using a more recent compiler, I'm getting a seg fault as soon as I launch the program, which I've tracked it to the initialization of the dependent constant.

Minimal equivalent example:

mystruct.h:

```
#include <string>
struct mystruct {
   static const string myconst;
}
```

mystruct.cc:

```
#include <mystruct.h>
const string mystruct::myconst = "a"
```

prog.cc:

```
#include <mystruct.h>
const string mydependentconst = mystruct::myconst + "b";
int main() {}
```

This code sometimes segfaults because `mystruct::myconst` has not yet been initialized when `mydependentconst` gets initialized.
I have fixed my code by making the variable initialization independent (effectively, `mydependenconst = "ab"`), but I would like to know: is it actually undefined behaviour and was I just lucky before?

I think this boils down to whether I can expect a specific order of initialization of constants in my `.o` files, or if I have to assume the order is unspecified.

Note that I have no problem using `mystruct::myconst` inside functions anywhere, I'm only getting this seg fault in this file-global constant initialization in `prog.cc`.

Context: this occurs in a 15-year old C++ project (using `g++` with `-std=gnu++98`) which I'm trying to revive on a newer OS. It works fine on CentOS 6, now I'm fixing it to work on CentOS 7 and next I will do more recent OS's too.

Comment: Don't you need to declare it as extern in `prog.cc`?

Comment: This is the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order.html)

Comment: @M.A No, because it's a static const in a struct. I would have had to otherwise.

Comment: @darcamo Thanks for the link to the duplicate, this is very helpful! I had never heard of the SIOF, now I'll read more about it.